# SQL Server: importing from Excel, only want the new entries

Tags: sql-server, dts, import-from-excel

The task is to have SQL Server read an Excel spreadsheet, and import only the new entries into a table. The entity is called **Provider**.

Consider an Excel spreadsheet like this:

[image]

Its target table is like this:

[image]

The task is to:

- using 2008 Express toolset
- import into an existing table in SQL Sever 2000
- existing data in the table! Identity with increment is PK. This is used as FK in another table, with references made.
- **import only the new rows from the spreadsheet!**
- ignore rows who don't exist in spreadsheet

**Question:**
How can I use the SQL 2008 toolset (Import and Export wizard likely) to achieve this goal? I suspect I'll need to "Write a query to specify the data to transfer".

Problem being is that I cannot find the query as the tool would be generating to make fine adjustments.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'd probably do is bulk load the excel data into a separate staging table within the database and then run an INSERT on the main table to copy over the records that don't exist.

e.g.

```
INSERT MyRealTable (ID, FirstName, LastName,.....)
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName,.....
FROM StagingTable s
    LEFT JOIN MyRealTable r ON s.ID = r.ID
WHERE r.ID IS NULL
```

Then drop the staging table when you're done.

Comment: and if you're on SQL Server 2008, by all means, use the new MERGE command!

Answer (score 0):

You can run some updates on that stage table before you load it, to clean it up, if you need to, as well.  UPDATE SET NAME = RTROM(LTRIM(Name))
FROM YOUR.STAGE.TABlE for example